# Covering 100% width and height of outer relative DIV with inner absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, tablet, absolute

I have an outer **relative** div with two inner **absolute** divs. The inner divs are supposed to completely cover the outer, but while they do so on a desktop, **on a tablet** there is some space between the inner div2 and the encompassing outer div. What's going on? Is this a bug??

Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoMJj.png).

```css
.problem-description {
  display:block;
  margin:20px;
}

.outer {
  width:300px; 
  height:200px;
  margin:60px auto;
  position:relative;
}
.inner1, .inner2 {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.inner1 {
  background:blue;  
}
.inner2 {
  background:white;
/*   background:url('https://nofri.es/wp-content/uploads/images/port-bubble2.svg'); */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"><span class="problem-description">the blue edge of .inner1 div bleeds around .inner2 on mobile</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot from your tablet?

Comment: I'm not really seeing where the problematic 'space' is?

Comment: @dom_ahdigital if you use the device "mode" in devtools, tablet, you will se a blue "border" to the white box.

Comment: does this happen on a real tablet or just in devtools?

Comment: This could be just a problem with the browser zoom. As I see, you are on 50%, so it could be that the outer pixelrows become half-transparent. Have you tryed it to turn it on 100%?

Comment: Would guess at anti aliasing if this is just happening in devtools.

Comment: I did not see your problem on tablet, but I can note that you do not need to put ```width: 100%;``` with ```left: 0; and right: 0;```

Comment: @cagcoach Don't have access to one atm. I've been using Chrome's dev tools and the re:view plugin to simulate the tablet viewport. In all 3 cases (tablet, chrome tools, re:view plugin) I saw that weird border. The screenshot attached above is of the chrome preview. Here's a screenshot using the plugin: [link](https://ibb.co/bZyXpm) sorry I can't post the real thing...

Comment: @mahmoud I do have that.

Comment: @Dejan.S I saw this on a table device (checked out my live site from a friend's device, and saw this nasty surprise). I was then able to "recreate" the problem using devtools and some plugin that previews different viewports. In all cases I saw the border

Comment: @cagcoach I tried width at 100%, but same thing:
[screenshot](https://ibb.co/h831FR)

Comment: @sashaikevich hmmm... when I open the snippet on my phone, I can see the white borders, but only them I click on zoom 50% or 25%...

Comment: @sashaikevich I don't mean the width of the div! The Top-Line in your screenshot says: iPad 768x1024 **50%** Online

Comment: @cagcoach Oops, neither did I. It was supposed to read "I tried *zoom* at 100%, but same thing"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to your outer div. Apparently it forces hardware acceleration, hiding the undesirable artifacts.

```
.outer {
  width:300px; 
  height:200px;
  margin:60px auto;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: This is the closest yet - top and left bleed is gone, but right and bottom is still there.

Comment: (applying the transform to .inner divs to get rid of the artifacts there didn't help...)

Comment: Interesting.. commenting and uncommenting this on codepen, for me at least, will show and hide the outline. Best to probably add the code and try on actual device.

Comment: will definitely give it a go. Thanks.